# Playing a sound in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read some threads about this topic, and currently have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];


NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testsoundsr.aiff",
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                               error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];



}
```

The sound is not played though, and I can only imagine that the problem is with the NSString definition which is used to reference the file

The file I'm trying to play is named 'testsoundsr.aiff' and I have dragged that into the project. Also I have added several frameworks to the project, including AudioToolBox.framework

---UPDATE---

I have now tried using an .mp3 file instead, but still getting no sound through.

Comment: The proper way to get the URL would be: `NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testsoundsr" withExtension:@"aiff"];`.

Comment: okay I had no idea that was possible. Still no sound going through though

Comment: Have you checked if `soundFileURL` is `nil` or not?

Comment: I tried checking with     NSLog(@"%@",soundFileURL);
and it seems to have the correct file pointed down, as it's referring to FrenzyF.app/testsoundsr.aiff

Answer (score -1):

Try `player.delegate = self` before `[player play]`

Comment: That brings up a semantic issue for me assigning from 'incompatible type const:strong
app can still run, but no sound

Comment: Try `NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];` instead of your NSURL statement, then use `filePath` instead of `soundFilePath` in the AVAudioPlayer statement that follows.

Comment: Also, do you have `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>` at the end of your `@interface` line in your h file?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer doesn’t require its delegate to be set. That only matters if you’re implementing any of the delegate methods, which is not what’s happening here. Also, `[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:…]` is equivalent to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:…]` under ARC. That isn’t the problem here either.

Comment: Okay I tried that, and no sound
Will be back in some hours, 1am here

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon
Can nobody see what could cause this? I'm out of ideas myself, other than starting over with some other solution